# Accepting HTTP requests in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, xamarin.ios

I have a small device that takes stills/videos. I need to let subscribers (IP addresses representing mobile/ios devices) know about the new stills/videos as they happen.

I want to prevent polling from mobile devices and have enable the mobile devices to accept a small HTTP request on a certain port number.

Is this possible? I am using MonoTouch, but the solution could be in Objective-C (I'll use bindings).

Comment: Can you use push notifications?

Comment: Push notifications is the way to go. Failing that you could set up an XMPP server and use that instead. Basically instead of polling on a HTTP port, the XMPP port is just open and new information is "pushed" down the connetion.

Comment: I can't use push notifications because the device/client may be disconnected from the internet on a local network.

Comment: have you looked at SignalR for iOS?

Comment: Just came across it. It might be an overkill for what I want to do. It is also not released yet. I think I am just going to do a poll at a certain interval for recently taken stills/videos.